# Drag and Drop Float Action menu Doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I have just created a float action menu all I need I want this float action menu Draggable I already created a Drag and Drop View class and created an Float Action menu object but It still doesn't work here's the Drag and drop Class

```
package niko.dragdrop.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * @author Niko
 * View Container to place the view wanted to be dragged
 */
public class DragDropView extends FrameLayout {

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public DragDropView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public DragDropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public DragDropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /** Adding draggable object to the dragView
     * @param draggableView - object to be dragged
     * @param - x horizontal position of the view
     * @param - y vertical position of the view
     * @param - width width of the view
     * @param - height height of the view
     */
    public void AddDraggableView(View draggableObject, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        LayoutParams lpDraggableView = new LayoutParams(width, height);
        lpDraggableView.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        lpDraggableView.leftMargin = x;
        lpDraggableView.topMargin = y;
        if(draggableObject instanceof ImageView) {
            ImageView ivDrag = (ImageView) draggableObject;
            ivDrag.setLayoutParams(lpDraggableView);
            ivDrag.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchToDrag);
            this.addView(ivDrag);
        } 
        //TODO implement to do other type of view
//      else if(draggableObject instanceof TextView) {
//          TextView tvDrag = (TextView) draggableObject;
//          tvDrag.setLayoutParams(lpDraggableView);
//          tvDrag.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchToDrag);
//          this.addView(tvDrag);
//      } 
//      else if(draggableObject instanceof Button) {
//          Button btnDrag = (Button) draggableObject;
//          btnDrag.setLayoutParams(lpDraggableView);
//          btnDrag.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchToDrag);
//          this.addView(btnDrag);
//      }

    }

    /**
     * Draggable object ontouch listener
     * Handle the movement of the object when dragged and dropped
     */
    private View.OnTouchListener OnTouchToDrag = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams dragParam = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    dragParam.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                    dragParam.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                    v.setLayoutParams(dragParam);
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                //  dragParam.height = 150;
                //  dragParam.width = 150;
                    dragParam.height = v.getHeight();
                                dragParam.width = v.getWidth();
                    dragParam.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                    dragParam.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                    v.setLayoutParams(dragParam);
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                //  dragParam.height = 100;
                //  dragParam.width = 100;
                        dragParam.height = v.getHeight();
                                dragParam.width = v.getWidth();
                    v.setLayoutParams(dragParam);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    };

}
```

and this is Float Action Menu Properties

```
FloatingActionMenu mainFM;

private Context context;
    mainFM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.mainFAB);
    context = this;
    FrameLayout llContainerMain = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    DragDropView dragDropView = new DragDropView(context);
    dragDropView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    FloatingActionMenu fam = new FloatingActionMenu(context);
    dragDropView.AddDraggableView(mainFM, 50, 50, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llContainerMain.addView(dragDropView);
```

If any one could help me to solve this case I would very thankful sorry If any thing isn't clear and sorry for my bad English

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: It suppose that It drag and drop but when I touch listner it didn't drag